Writing section headings in Xcode comments (for C++)
According to this SO post, one can boldface a word in Xcode (C++) comments with
/// This @b word in my C++ comment is boldfaced.

However, I would like to enter section titles into my code, all in bold, for better readability of my code. Of course I could put @b in front of every word of the title, but maybe there is an easier/more proper way to do it?
